# How to find the exact line that caused an error in C# code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception

I am executing a c# script (inside SSIS, an ETL tool) in a modified visual studio 2008 (actually called BIDS). I get an error, but the error message does not let me trace the line that caused the error. How do I find out which line is causing the problem.

I tried using, try catch and my SSIS package ran without errors. But, when I remove the try catch, the package execution shows an error. Anyway, all this talk about SSIS is not really needed. Its the error/exception catching which matters here.

```
    try
    {            
        //my code here
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
    }
```

The error info is given below -

```
Error: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at ST_LongCodeNameHere.csproj.ScriptMain.Main()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()
```

Comment: Are you in debug mode?

Comment: Is there no way to step through the code line-per-line?

Comment: if u are in debug mode in VS u can enable all exceptions under the menu Debug.

Comment: @AbinMathew - what do you mean by debug mode ? How would that affect me ?

Comment: @Serv - In java, its so easy to get the exact line that caused an exception. Can C# do that too ?

Comment: remove `try..catch` and you will get exception on exact line of error

Comment: trust me its much easier in c#

Comment: @SaghirA.Khatri - but the error above does not guide me to the problem line. In Eclipse and java, this is so easy !

Comment: @zxc -then, please show me how to do it. Thanks

Comment: @AbinMathew - how do I do it ?

Comment: @Blasto cant you put some breakpoints into it?

Comment: @AbinMathew - What does that do ? Its just opening up a file selection window for me.

Comment: @AbinMathew he/she is trying to debug a script component in SSIS, not a C# class

Comment: possible duplicate of [Debugging in SSIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653274/debugging-in-ssis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the page "[Coding and Debugging the Script Component](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136033%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)" on Technet.

In particular, the section "Debugging the Script Component" might give you some pointers:

> The Script component does not support the use of breakpoints.
>   Therefore, you cannot step through your code and examine values as the
>   package runs. You can monitor the execution of the Script component by
>   using the following methods:
>
> - Interrupt execution and display a modal message by using the    MessageBox.Show method in the System.Windows.Forms namespace. (Remove 
>     this code after you complete the debugging process.)
> - Raise events for informational messages, warnings, and errors. The    FireInformation, FireWarning, and FireError methods display the event 
>     description in the Visual Studio Output window. However, the
>     FireProgress method, the Console.Write method, and Console.WriteLine
>     method do not display any information in the Output window. Messages
>     from the FireProgress event appear on the Progress tab of SSIS
>     Designer. For more information, see Raising Events in the Script
>     Component.
> - Log events or user-defined messages to enabled logging providers. For    more information, see Logging in the Script Component.
>
> If you just want to examine the output of a Script component
>   configured as a source or as a transformation, without saving the data
>   to a destination, you can stop the data flow with a Row Count
>   Transformation and attach a data viewer to the output of the Script
>   component. For information about data viewers, see Debugging Data
>   Flow.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Find the image]

Chcek all boxes and try to run the code.